# Redireccionamiento a una pagin html con node js

Tags: javascript, nodejs, ejs, inicializacion, redireccionamiento

soy un estudiante de programacion de bachillerato y estoy haciendo un proyecto de facturacion sere breve mi problema es este, al momento de iniciar o registrarme necesito que me redireccione a otra pagina pero el asunto es este estoy utilizando node js y ala hora de hacer la validacion de los datos no se como implementar una variable o algo que me redireccione a una pagina que es html [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Astro, bienvenido, la preguntas/respuesta debe ser autocontenida, esto es que no dependa de imágenes o enlaces, te sugiero que la edites, y la adaptes a los requerimientos del sitio, para que no sea cerrada, y evitar recibir votos negativos,
mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  

aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Te invito a hacer el [tour].Por favor no publiques código o mensajes de error/trazas de pila en imágenes, publica directamente el texto del código, el texto de los errores y los _stack traces_. Esto hace que sea menos complicado, para quien quiera ayudarte, investigar sobre el tema y hacer sus propias pruebas/adaptaciones al código, al escribir una respuesta y de esa forma aumenta tus posibilidades de encontrar la ayuda que buscas. Un saludo.